# How to add percent of each category to stacked bar chart (ggplot2) (for a "non-percent" stacked chart)

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I add the percent of each category to a stacked bar chart of the axis and not the fill. For example, I have the following dataset:

```
df<-structure(list(age_group = structure(c(3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("65+", "55-64", 
"45-54", "35-44", "25-34", "18-24"), class = "factor"), Gender = c("F", 
"M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", 
"M")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), .Names = c("age_group", "Gender"))

dat <- aggregate(list(value = 1:NROW(df)), df[c("age_group", "Gender")], length)
dat$proportion <- ave(dat$value, dat$age_group, FUN = function(x) (x/sum(x)*100))
dat$proportionR <- round(dat$proportion, digits =0)

dat<-dat %>%
  group_by(age_group) %>%
  mutate(age_per = sum(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(age_per = round((age_per/sum(value))*100))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = age_group, y = value, fill = Gender)) +
  geom_col() + coord_flip() + ylab("Visits 2018-2019") +xlab("") +
  scale_fill_manual(values= c("#740404", "#AB6868", "#D5B3B3"), labels = c("Females", "Males", "N/A")) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(age_per, "%")), hjust = 2.7, position = "stack", color = "white", size =5)
```

[image]

What I would like is an automated way to add the **total percent** for each group from the y-axis while disregarding the percentages within each group. My work flow identifies the correct percent but replicates it over each subgroup within the stack. I would like the `geom_text` to be placed in the white space right after bar ends.

Just as a note, the question is not a duplicate of the following SO Q -[Adding percentage labels to a bar chart in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249943/adding-percentage-labels-to-a-bar-chart-in-ggplot2) -because this question deals with percents when there are stacked groups within each bar (the former is just for bar plots).

Also, emphasis on automated. I can do the following but in my real data set I have many more age group intervals, which makes the below approach untenable.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = age_group, y = value, fill = Gender)) +
  geom_col() + coord_flip() + ylab("Visits 2018-2019") +xlab("") +
  scale_fill_manual(values= c("#740404", "#AB6868", "#D5B3B3"), labels = c("Females", "Males", "N/A")) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
  geom_text(aes(y= 5.2, x=1, label = "33%"), color = "#740404", size =5) +
  geom_text(aes(y= 3.2, x=2, label = "20%"), color = "#740404", size =5) +
  geom_text(aes(y= 7.2, x=3, label = "47%"), color = "#740404", size =5)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, what are the exact numbers you want to add?

Comment: @PoGibas I would like just a single number following the bar, that number should be the same as the repeated numbers you currently see above in the first chart. The percents are calculated as the total for each age group (disregarding gender) divided by the total number of values in the dataset. See additions above.

Answer (score 1):

Consider annotating using a grouping percent calculation. Since you need to add three numbers with a series of six, `annotate` can diverge from grouping series. Also, use the appropriate gender and age group percentages. And below another `base::ave` call replaces your `dplyr::group_by`:

```
agg_df <- aggregate(list(value = 1:NROW(df)), df[c("age_group", "Gender")], length)

dat <- within(agg_df, {
  proportion <- ave(value, age_group, FUN = function(x) (x/sum(x)*100))
  proportionR <- round(proportion, digits=0)

  age_per <- round((ave(value, age_group, Gender, FUN=sum) / sum(value)) * 100)      
  grp_pct <- round((ave(value, age_group, FUN=sum) / sum(value)) * 100)
})

dat
#   age_group Gender value grp_pct age_per proportionR proportion
# 1     45-54      F     2      33      13          40   40.00000
# 2     35-44      F     1      20       7          33   33.33333
# 3     25-34      F     2      47      13          29   28.57143
# 4     45-54      M     3      33      20          60   60.00000
# 5     35-44      M     2      20      13          67   66.66667
# 6     25-34      M     5      47      33          71   71.42857



ggplot(dat, aes(x = age_group, y = value, fill = Gender)) +
  geom_col() + coord_flip() + ylab("Visits 2018-2019") +xlab("") +
  scale_fill_manual(values= c("#740404", "#AB6868", "#D5B3B3"), 
                    labels = c("Females", "Males", "N/A")) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(age_per, "%")), hjust = 2.7, 
            position = "stack", color = "white", size =5) + 
  annotate("text", x=1, y=5.25, label = paste0(dat$grp_pct[[1]], "%")) +
  annotate("text", x=2, y=3.25, label = paste0(dat$grp_pct[[2]], "%")) +
  annotate("text", x=3, y=7.25, label = paste0(dat$grp_pct[[3]], "%"))
```

[image: Plot Output]

---

For dynamic annotating, you may have to use the functional form of `ggplot` using `Reduce` where the `+` (not actually the plus arithmetic operator) is exposed as `+.gg()` operator. Then, call `mapply` to iterate through `unique(grp_pct)` to pass in x coordinate location and annotate label. Remaining challenge is that the best y coordinate is unknown.

```
Reduce(ggplot2:::`+.gg`, 

       c(list(ggplot(dat, aes(x = age_group, y = value, fill = Gender)),
              geom_col(), coord_flip(), ylab("Visits 2018-2019"), xlab(""),
              scale_fill_manual(values= c("#740404", "#AB6868", "#D5B3B3"),
                              labels = c("Females", "Males", "N/A")),
              theme(legend.title=element_blank()),
              geom_text(aes(label = paste0(age_per, "%")), hjust = 2.7, 
                        position = "stack", color = "white", size =5) 
         ),
         Map(function(x_loc, g_lab) annotate("text", x=x_loc, y=7.25,
                                                label = paste0(g_lab, "%")),
             seq(length(unique(dat$grp_pct))), unique(dat$grp_pct)
         )
       )
)
```

[image: Plot Output]

Comment: Unfortunately this is not workflow that is generalizable to many more y-axis categories. As I mentioned in my question, my real data set has many more categories.

Comment: Simply remove the `geom_text()` call.

Comment: Yeah I know, but please read the entire question. I need an approach that can be generalized to many categories. What  you have done automates the label text but not the label position, which is much more important from an automated perspective (much easier to write actual text for many categories than identifying correct position for many categories).

Comment: Understood. You modified your post while I was answering. There is a way to incorporate a loop inside the ggplot call. Can update by tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that! Thanks so much.