# Show % Ratio of Fill Data in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following piece of R code through which I want to see the Satisfaction Rate based on Type of Travel.

```
unipar = theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 10), 
        axis.title = element_text(size = 11), 
        title = element_text(size = 13, face = "bold"))

col1 = "Set2"

ggplot(customer_raw, aes(x=TypeTravel, fill=Satisfaction)) + 
  geom_bar()+ 
  unipar + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette=col1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..prop..), group = 1), 
            stat= "count", size = 3.3, position = position_stack(0.06))+
  geom_text(aes(label = ..count.., group = 1), 
            stat= "count", size = 3.3, position = position_stack(0.95)) +
  labs(title = 'Satisfaction Rate (%) based on Type of Travel', y = '', x = '')
```

Currently, I am only able to show the count of each level within my variable and the % of each variable. This is how my graph looks:

[image: graph]

Please help so that I am able to show the % of each level above each bar & the % split between Satisfied & Non-Satisfied within each bar.

Comment: Does this post answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744507/how-to-show-percentages-in-stacked-column-with-ggplot-geom-bar

Comment: Hi! yes the link helped! thanks alot.