# Display percentages within category and also for entire sample with ordinal variable in facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, geom-col

I'm trying to modify @DaveArmstrong 's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72350956/displaying-percentages-within-category-for-continuous-ordered-variable-with-ggp/72351235?noredirect=1#comment127823172_72351235) because I'm also trying to display the percent for the entire sample, aka for White, Black, Hispanic, and Other together, and display that next to each individual race (calling it "all" or something like that).

I tried to modify @DaveArmstrong 's great answer to that question in a few ways, including `mutate()` before (and after) grouping by question and race, but haven't gotten it to work quite right yet.

```
set.seed(123)

d <- data.frame(
  race = sample(c("White", "Hispanic", "Black", "Other"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  question1 = sample(0:4, 100, replace = TRUE),
  question2 = sample(0:4, 100, replace = TRUE),
  question3 = sample(0:4, 100, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Comment: I am fairly sure this is a duplicate or something very close to  [Add overall bar and perc labels to geom_bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70496234/add-overall-bar-and-perc-labels-to-geom-bar) . I will not mark it though, because otherwise your question will be directly closed.

Comment: It does look like your answer in that question is fairly similar, and the solution is creating a second dataframe and then using bind_rows() to bind the two together. I'll see if I can adapt that code.

Comment: give me a shout if you should struggle, or even if it helps (I can then close this as a duplicate). Please don't delete this question. The more questions are linked, the more people can find an answer to their future question

Comment: @tjebo okay, I figured it out--although I'm not actually sure it should be marked as a duplicate, because these data have to be pivoted long and therefore it ends up being a bit of a different thing (though much of the code remains the same, to be fair).

Comment: maybe post it as an answer to your own question then!

Answer (score 2):

This was not easy for me, but with the answer from @tjebo here [Add overall bar and perc labels to geom_bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70496234/add-overall-bar-and-perc-labels-to-geom-bar) for the first time I really get an inside of how to do this. Nevertheless it was hard to implement it with faceting. Therefore I don't think that it is a duplicate.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)

sPalette <- "Purples" %>% 
  sapply(., function(x) brewer.pal(8, name = x)) %>% 
  as.vector

df_perc <- d %>% 
  pivot_longer(-race) %>%
  count(name, race, value) %>% 
  group_by(name, race) %>%
  mutate(value = as.factor(value),
         pct= prop.table(n) * 100)

total <- df_perc %>%
  group_by(name, value) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(n)) %>% 
  mutate(race = "Total", 
         pct= n*100/sum(n)) %>% 
  select(name, race, value, n, pct) 

bind_rows(df_perc, total) %>%
  mutate(race = fct_relevel(race, c("White", "Black", "Hispanic", "Other", "Total"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=race, y=pct, fill=value)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_fill()) +
  facet_wrap(.~name)+
  labs(x="", y="Percentage (within Race)", fill="Response") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  geom_text(aes(label =  round(pct, 1)),
            position = position_fill(vjust = .5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = sPalette) + 
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position = "top", 
        panel.grid = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adding my own solution after playing around with the answer from another question that @tjebo provided:

```
d2 <- d %>%
  select(question1, question2, question3) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "question", values_to = "vals") %>% 
  group_by(question, vals) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  group_by(question) %>% 
  mutate(pct = n/sum(n), race = "All")

d3 <- d %>%
  pivot_longer(-race, names_to = "question", values_to = "vals") %>% 
  group_by(question, race, vals) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  group_by(question, race) %>% 
  mutate(pct = n/sum(n)) 

bind_rows(d2, d3) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=race, y=pct, fill=as.factor(vals))) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~question) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales:::percent) + 
  labs(x="", 
       y="Percentage", 
       fill="Response") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = "top", 
        panel.grid = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1))
```

[image]