# Adding percentage labels in barplots (gglot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart

I have the following dataset with the following variables indicating whether a person used their phone (a dummy variable with 1 = used the phone ("Yes") and 0 ("No") else); their ID and district and sub-district  they live in. Note that a same person may have been recorded twice or more under different sub-districts. However, I only want to count such a person once, that is, consider only unique IDs.

```
district sub_district   id  used_phone
    A   SX  1   Yes
    A   SX  2   Yes
    A   SX  3   No
    A   SX  4   No
    A   SY  4   No
    A   SY  5   Yes
    A   SZ  6   Yes
    A   SX  6   Yes
    A   SZ  7   No
    B   RX  8   No
    B   RV  9   No
    B   RX  9   No
    B   RV  10  Yes
    B   RV  11  Yes
    B   RT  12  Yes
    B   RT  13  Yes
    B   RV  13  Yes
    B   RT  14  No
    B   RX  14  No
```

N.B: used_phone is a factor variable

For the above dataset, I want to plot a distribution of "whether a person used a phone" for which I was using the following code:

```
  ggplot(df, aes(x=used_phone)) +
  geom_bar(color = "black", fill = "aquamarine4", position = "dodge") +
  labs(x="Used phone", y = "Number of people") +
  ggtitle("Whether person used phone") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)))
```

This code works fine. However, I want to do two things:

1. Add % labels for each group (yes & no) over the respective bars but y-axis to show the "count"
2. Plot the graph such that it only considers the unique IDs

Looking forward to solving this with your help as I am novice in R.

Thanks,
Rachita

Comment: Could you please include a minimal subset of your data as a dataframe object? Maybe use `dput(df)` . This allows potential solutions to be tested and verifited. Have a look at [mre].

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Peter! I have updated the dataset. Unfortunately, I can not post the original dataset hence, made one up for your review. Hope this is fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding percentage labels to a bar chart in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249943/adding-percentage-labels-to-a-bar-chart-in-ggplot2)

Comment: As for the unique ids, look into using something like `df[!duplicated(df$id),]`

Comment: Hi, @4redwood: the said link was not helpful in my case. However, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the duplicates in **id** are id's living in different sub_district at the same time and you want to not double count them, I delete the variable `sub_district`.
Then erase all duplicates, count the phones and calculate the percentage. The DF coming from this is shown.
ggplot is with `geom_col` and the percentage on the axis with `scales`.

I have commented out two lines of code which allows you to facet for district in your ggplot. The diagram coming out of this is attached at the bottom.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text="district sub_district   id  used_phone
    A   SX  1   Yes
    A   SX  2   Yes
    A   SX  3   No
    A   SX  4   No
    A   SY  4   No
    A   SY  5   Yes
    A   SZ  6   Yes
    A   SX  6   Yes
    A   SZ  7   No
    B   RX  8   No
    B   RV  9   No
    B   RX  9   No
    B   RV  10  Yes
    B   RV  11  Yes
    B   RT  12  Yes
    B   RT  13  Yes
    B   RV  13  Yes
    B   RT  14  No
    B   RX  14  No", header = T)
table(df$used_phone)
#> 
#>  No Yes 
#>   9  10

ddf <- df %>%
  select(-sub_district) %>%        # delete sub_district
  distinct(id, .keep_all = T) %>%  # unique id`s`
  #group_by(district) %>% 
  count(used_phone) %>%            # cout phones
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n))         # calculate percentage

ddf
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   used_phone     n   pct
#>   <chr>      <int> <dbl>
#> 1 No             6 0.429
#> 2 Yes            8 0.571

ggplot(ddf, aes(used_phone, pct, fill = used_phone)) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') + 
  #facet_wrap(~district) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("aquamarine4", "aquamarine3")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

[image]

[image]

---

New Addition based on comment:

- wants y-axis in counts
- wants percentage as labels over the bar
- wants as facet for district

```
ddf <- df %>%
  select(-sub_district) %>%        # delete sub_district
  distinct(id, .keep_all = T) %>%  # unique id`s`
  group_by(district) %>% 
  count(used_phone) %>%            # cout phones
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n),         # calculate percentage
         label = paste0(round(pct*100, 2), '%'))     

ggplot(ddf, aes(used_phone, n, fill = used_phone)) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') + 
  facet_wrap(~district) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("aquamarine4", "aquamarine3")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = label),
           position = position_stack(vjust = 1.05),
           size = 3) +
  labs(y='count')
```

[image]

---

*new addition*
change the basis for percent

```
ddf <- df %>%
  select(-sub_district) %>%        # delete sub_district
  distinct(id, .keep_all = T) %>%  # unique id`s`
  mutate(ssum = n()) %>% 
  group_by(district) %>% 
  count(used_phone, ssum) %>%            # cout phones
  mutate(pct = n / ssum,         # calculate percentage
         label = paste0(round(pct*100, 2), '%'))
```

I have introduced a new variable which sums the numbers up before grouping. That gives:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, MarBlo. However, I would like to have my y-axis as "count" and not %. Percentages can be as labels over the bars. Could you help me do that for the facet plot for districts?

Comment: @Rachita I made a new edit and think this is what you want. The DF has identical values for the 2 districts.

Comment: yes, I ran it and have got the bar labels! However, the percentages within the districts are not quite right as they are calculated with denominator = total number of observations in district A + B. I would want the denominator to be the total number of observations in the respective district. Could you tweak your code based on this?

Comment: @Rachita I have an additional edit. Please, have look.

Comment: thanks so much, MarBlo!! You're a savior. However, `mutate(ssum = n()) %>% ` should come after grouping by district. I got it correct after tweaking that!

Comment: @Rachita you are welcome. I am happy it helped. Voting up is an option

Comment: I have done that! However, my reputation yet doesn't allow my upvote to be showcased publicly.

Comment: @Rachita I recognized that you changed the accepted answer from mine to monte's answer. May I ask why?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this platform -- thought we could accept multiple answers. Could I request you to review another question of mine and see if could help in that?

Comment: @Rachita SO is a very friendly and helpful platform. The people on SO helped me a lot. I am sure, if you post your question you will get help. If I have an answer to your question I will try to contribute. Your style of asking makes me believe, that you will get answers.

Comment: Thank you for your encouraging words! Another question of mine on which I am seeking help is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62538923/splitting-multiple-date-and-time-variables-naming-those-as-per-original-variab

Answer (score 1):

Here is one suggestion that could work:

1. Summarize your df based on `used_phone` and count total number of people who have either used phone and not.
2. Based on the summarized count, you can calculate percent share and with that you can add `label` cloumn which is just percent share with `%` sign
3. You can plot using ggplot and using the new summarized `df`. You can use `geom_text()` to add percentage labels at the top of bars, use `vjust` argument in `position_stack()` to play around with label's position.

```r
df %>% 
distinct(.keep_all = T) %>%
  group_by(used_phone) %>% 
  summarize(n()) %>% 
  setNames(., c('used_phone', 'count')) %>% 
  mutate('share' = count/sum(count),
         'label' = paste0(round(share*100, 2), '%')) -> df

  ggplot(df, aes(y=count, x=used_phone)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity',
           color = "black", 
           fill = "aquamarine4", 
           position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = label),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 1.02),
            size = 3) +
  labs(title = 'Whether person used phone',
       x = 'Used Phone',
       y = 'Number of People') +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: The original DF had 19 rows, all with either *yes* or *no* in `used_phone`. So there can not be exact 50% usage rate for both. And @Rachita wanted to count only unique id's.

Comment: I created this answer before the question was updated with new data, thanks for pointing out the distinct condition, I have modified the code to include that.

Comment: Thanks, both!! The code works fine except the distinct condition - it is still counting the number of yes/no as per the non-unique IDs. I tried both of your versions. Any idea to work around with this?