# Splitting multiple date and time variables & computing time average in R

Tags: r, datetime, split, lubridate, posixct

I have the following dataset wherein, I have the person's ID, district and sub-district they live in along with the last date/time on which they uploaded data to the server. The variables "last_down_" contain the last date/time on which a person the uploaded data and are named in such a way that they show the date on which I had downloaded the data on the same. For example, "last_upload_2020-06-12" would mean I downloaded the data from the server on 12th June.

For the below dataset, I would like to spilt the date and time in each of the variables (all at once) in a way that the new separated variables which are created go by the name "last_date_(my download date)" & "last_time_(my download date)"

```
 district block id  last_upload_2020-06-12 last_upload_2020-06-13 last_upload_2020-06-14 last_upload_2020-06-15
    A   X   11  2020-02-06 11:53:19.0   2020-02-06 11:53:19.0   2020-02-06 11:53:19.0   2020-02-06 11:53:19.0
    A   X   12  2020-06-11 12:40:26.0   2020-06-11 12:40:26.0   2020-06-14 11:40:26.0   2020-06-15 18:50:26.0
    A   X                                                       2020-06-14 11:08:12.0   2020-06-14 11:08:12.0
    A   X   14  2020-06-12 11:31:07.0   2020-06-13 11:31:07.0   2020-06-14 17:37:07.0   2020-06-14 17:37:07.0
    A   Y   15  2020-06-10 12:45:48.0   2020-06-10 12:45:48.0   2020-06-10 12:45:48.0   2020-06-10 12:45:48.0
    A   Y   16  2020-04-04 02:26:57.0   2020-04-04 02:26:57.0   2020-04-04 02:26:57.0   2020-04-04 02:26:57.0
    A   Y   17  2020-03-31 08:10:03.0   2020-03-31 08:10:03.0   2020-03-31 08:10:03.0   2020-03-31 08:10:03.0
    A   Y   18  2020-05-30 12:08:15.0   2020-05-30 12:08:15.0   2020-05-30 12:08:15.0   2020-05-30 12:08:15.0
    A   Z   19  2020-04-09 15:21:52.0   2020-04-09 15:21:52.0   2020-04-09 15:21:52.0   2020-04-09 15:21:52.0
    A   Z   20  2020-05-30 17:42:33.0   2020-05-30 17:42:33.0   2020-05-30 17:42:33.0   2020-05-30 17:42:33.0
    A   Z   21  2020-04-12 14:23:29.0   2020-04-12 14:23:29.0   2020-04-12 14:23:29.0   2020-04-12 14:23:29.0
    A   Z   22  2020-05-13 23:18:19.0   2020-05-13 23:18:19.0   2020-05-13 23:18:19.0   2020-05-13 23:18:19.0
    A   X   23  2020-04-30 09:53:31.0   2020-04-30 09:53:31.0   2020-04-30 09:53:31.0   2020-04-30 09:53:31.0
    A   X   24  2020-06-10 10:28:59.0   2020-06-10 10:28:59.0   2020-06-10 10:28:59.0   2020-06-15 11:31:33.0
    A   Y   25              
    A   Y   26  2020-05-30 12:14:09.0   2020-05-30 12:14:09.0   2020-05-30 12:14:09.0   2020-05-30 12:14:09.0
    B   E   31              
    B   C   32  2020-06-12 16:43:23.0   2020-06-12 16:43:23.0   2020-06-12 16:43:23.0   2020-06-12 16:43:23.0
    B   C   33  2019-10-24 22:30:35.0   2019-10-24 22:30:35.0   2019-10-24 22:30:35.0   2019-10-24 22:30:35.0
    B   C   34  2020-06-09 15:38:18.0   2020-06-09 15:38:18.0   2020-06-09 15:38:18.0   2020-06-15 14:35:41.0
    B   C   35  2020-06-11 14:39:51.0   2020-06-11 14:39:51.0   2020-06-11 14:39:51.0   2020-06-11 14:39:51.0
    B   D   36  2020-06-12 11:53:15.0   2020-06-12 11:53:15.0   2020-06-12 11:53:15.0   2020-06-15 13:02:39.0
    B   D   37  2020-04-21 15:43:43.0   2020-04-21 15:43:43.0   2020-04-21 15:43:43.0   2020-04-21 15:43:43.0
    B   D   38  2020-05-13 04:07:17.0   2020-05-13 04:07:17.0   2020-05-13 04:07:17.0   2020-05-13 04:07:17.0
    B   E   39  2020-04-30 13:51:20.0   2020-04-30 13:51:20.0   2020-04-30 13:51:20.0   2020-04-30 13:51:20.0
    B   E   40  2020-05-12 16:51:01.0   2020-05-12 16:51:01.0   2020-05-12 16:51:01.0   2020-05-12 16:51:01.0
    B   E   41  2020-04-16 12:14:24.0   2020-04-16 12:14:24.0   2020-04-16 12:14:24.0   2020-04-16 12:14:24.0
    B   C   42  2018-06-07 15:12:18.0   2018-06-07 15:12:18.0   2018-06-07 15:12:18.0   2018-06-07 15:12:18.0
    B   D   43  2019-09-28 10:08:51.0   2019-09-28 10:08:51.0   2019-09-28 10:08:51.0   2019-09-28 10:08:51.0
```

N.B: my date/time variables are numeric.

Once I get the data in shape, I would also like to do the following:

1. Get the year and month of all observations under "last_upload_2020-06-12" in a separate column.
2. Similarly, for the last date in my dataset that is "last_upload_2020-06-15". Can I automate R picking the last date something like Sys.Date()-1? I will always have the data for one date less than current.
3. Calculate the average upload time per ID, i.e., generally around what time does a person upload data to the server? Average should be based on unique time values.

Would be extremely helpful if someone could help solve this!

Thanks,
Rachita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Df looked so complicated that I thought it might be better to replicate it.
I then used a function to take every column you wanted and separate it into the *last_date* and *last_time* as wanted. Inside the function the temporary DF is `cbind` to a DF built outside of the loop. This DF consisted out of the columns which are not treated in the loop.
The result of this loop is the DF as wanted. [colnames got a little long]

The key for the second task was to transfer to `last_time` to hours, then grouping und summarizing.

I hope this is what you wanted.

I think with this as a basis you can deal with no2.

There were some warnings which had to do with NA's.

More explanation in the reprex below.

```r
library(tidyverse)


df <- read.table(text = '
district block id  last_upload_2020_06_12 last_upload_2020_06_13 last_upload_2020_06_14 last_upload_2020_06_15
"A"   "X"   11  "2020-02-06 11:53:19.0"   "2020-02-06 11:53:19.0"   "2020-02-06 11:53:19.0"   "2020-02-06 11:53:19.0"
"A"   "X"   12  "2020-06-11 12:40:26.0"   "2020-06-11 12:40:26.0"   "2020-06-14 11:40:26.0"   "2020-06-15 18:50:26.0"
"A"   "X"   NA  "NA"                      "NA"                      "2020-06-14 11:0812.0"    "2020-06-14 11:0812.0"
"A"   "X"   14  "2020-06-12 11:31:07.0"   "2020-06-13 11:31:07.0"   "2020-06-14 17:37:07.0"   "2020-06-14 17:37:07.0"
"A"   "Y"   15  "2020-06-10 12:45:48.0"   "2020-06-10 12:45:48.0"   "2020-06-10 12:45:48.0"   "2020-06-10 12:45:48.0"
"A"   "Y"   16  "2020-04-04 02:26:57.0"   "2020-04-04 02:26:57.0"   "2020-04-04 02:26:57.0"   "2020-04-04 02:26:57.0"
"A"   "Y"   17  "2020-03-31 08:10:03.0"   "2020-03-31 08:10:03.0"   "2020-03-31 08:10:03.0"   "2020-03-31 08:10:03.0"
"A"   "Y"   18  "2020-05-30 12:08:15.0"   "2020-05-30 12:08:15.0"   "2020-05-30 12:08:15.0"   "2020-05-30 12:08:15.0"
"A"   "Z"   19  "2020-04-09 15:21:52.0"   "2020-04-09 15:21:52.0"   "2020-04-09 15:21:52.0"   "2020-04-09 15:21:52.0"
"A"   "Z"   20  "2020-05-30 17:42:33.0"   "2020-05-30 17:42:33.0"   "2020-05-30 17:42:33.0"   "2020-05-30 17:42:33.0"
"A"   "Z"   21  "2020-04-12 14:23:29.0"   "2020-04-12 14:23:29.0"   "2020-04-12 14:23:29.0"   "2020-04-12 14:23:29.0"
"A"   "Z"   22  "2020-05-13 23:18:19.0"   "2020-05-13 23:18:19.0"   "2020-05-13 23:18:19.0"   "2020-05-13 23:18:19.0"
"A"   "X"   23  "2020-04-30 09:53:31.0"   "2020-04-30 09:53:31.0"   "2020-04-30 09:53:31.0"   "2020-04-30 09:53:31.0"
"A"   "X"   24  "2020-06-10 10:28:59.0"   "2020-06-10 10:28:59.0"   "2020-06-10 10:28:59.0"   "2020-06-15 11:31:33.0"
"A"   "Y"   25  " "                        ""                     ""                         ""
"A"   "Y"   26  "2020-05-3012:14:09.0"   "2020-05-30 12:14:09.0"   "2020-05-30 12:14:09.0"   "2020-05-30 12:14:09.0"
"B"   "E"   31  ""            ""                      ""                        ""          ""
"B"   "C"   32  "2020-06-1 16:43:23.0"   "2020-06-12 16:43:23.0"   "2020-06-12 16:43:23.0"   "2020-06-12 16:43:23.0"
"B"   "C"   33  "2019-10-24 22:30:35.0"   "2019-10-24 22:30:35.0"   "2019-10-24 22:30:35.0"   "2019-10-24 22:30:35.0"
"B"   "C"   34  "2020-06-09 15:38:18.0"   "2020-06-09 15:38:18.0"   "2020-06-09 15:38:18.0"   "2020-06-15 14:35:41.0"
"B"   "C"   35  "2020-06-11 14:39:51.0"   "2020-06-11 14:39:51.0"   "2020-06-11 14:39:51.0"   "2020-06-11 14:39:51.0"
"B"   "D"   36  "2020-06-12 11:53:15.0"   "2020-06-12 11:53:15.0"   "2020-06-12 11:53:15.0"   "2020-06-15 13:02:39.0"
"B"   "D"   37  "2020-04-21 15:43:43.0"   "2020-04-21 15:43:43.0"   "2020-04-21 15:43:43.0"   "2020-04-21 15:43:43.0"
"B"   "D"   38  "2020-05-13 04:07:17.0"   "2020-05-13 04:07:17.0"   "2020-05-13 04:07:17.0"   "2020-05-13 04:07:17.0"
"B"   "E"   39  "2020-04-30 13:51:20.0"   "2020-04-30 13:51:20.0"   "2020-04-30 13:51:20.0"   "2020-04-30 13:51:20.0"
"B"   "E"   40  "2020-05-12 16:51:01.0"   "2020-05-12 16:51:01.0"   "2020-05-12 16:51:01.0"   "2020-05-12 16:51:01.0"
"B"   "E"   41  "2020-04-16 12:14:24.0"   "2020-04-16 12:14:24.0"   "2020-04-16 12:14:24.0"   "2020-04-16 12:14:24.0"
"B"   "C"   42  "2018-06-07 15:12:18.0"   "2018-06-07 15:12:18.0"   "2018-06-07 15:12:18.0"   "2018-06-07 15:12:18.0"
"B"   "D"   43  "2019-09-28 10:08:51.0"   "2019-09-28 10:08:51.0"   "2019-09-28 10:08:51.0"   "2019-09-28 10:08:51.0"
           ', header =T)


# TASK: create for each column which contains 'last_upload' new columns 
# with date and time

# get the colnames of the cols to be split or separated
ccl <- colnames(df %>% select(last_upload_2020_06_12:last_upload_2020_06_15))

# create new DF with first 3 columns, to which other columns are bound in
# the following function
dff <- df %>% select(district:id) 

# function to separate each col in ccl to _date and _time
for (cl in ccl) {
  tmp <- separate(df,
    col = cl, sep = " ",
    into = c(paste0(cl, "_date"), paste0(cl, "_time"))
  ) %>%
    select(contains("_date") | contains("_time"))
  dff <- cbind(dff, tmp)
}


dff %>% head()
#>   district block id last_upload_2020_06_12_date last_upload_2020_06_12_time
#> 1        A     X 11                  2020-02-06                  11:53:19.0
#> 2        A     X 12                  2020-06-11                  12:40:26.0
#> 3        A     X NA                        <NA>                        <NA>
#> 4        A     X 14                  2020-06-12                  11:31:07.0
#> 5        A     Y 15                  2020-06-10                  12:45:48.0
#> 6        A     Y 16                  2020-04-04                  02:26:57.0
#>   last_upload_2020_06_13_date last_upload_2020_06_13_time
#> 1                  2020-02-06                  11:53:19.0
#> 2                  2020-06-11                  12:40:26.0
#> 3                        <NA>                        <NA>
#> 4                  2020-06-13                  11:31:07.0
#> 5                  2020-06-10                  12:45:48.0
#> 6                  2020-04-04                  02:26:57.0
#>   last_upload_2020_06_14_date last_upload_2020_06_14_time
#> 1                  2020-02-06                  11:53:19.0
#> 2                  2020-06-14                  11:40:26.0
#> 3                  2020-06-14                   11:0812.0
#> 4                  2020-06-14                  17:37:07.0
#> 5                  2020-06-10                  12:45:48.0
#> 6                  2020-04-04                  02:26:57.0
#>   last_upload_2020_06_15_date last_upload_2020_06_15_time
#> 1                  2020-02-06                  11:53:19.0
#> 2                  2020-06-15                  18:50:26.0
#> 3                  2020-06-14                   11:0812.0
#> 4                  2020-06-14                  17:37:07.0
#> 5                  2020-06-10                  12:45:48.0
#> 6                  2020-04-04                  02:26:57.0

# TASK: Calculate the average time of a day each id does a download
# new DF from original brought into long format
# split the date/time into last_date and last_time
ddf <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = last_upload_2020_06_12:last_upload_2020_06_15) %>%
  separate(col = value, sep = ' ', into = c('last_date', 'last_time')) %>%
  mutate(last_date = lubridate::ymd(last_date), last_time= lubridate::hms(last_time))


# calculating the mean hour of the day at which each id does a 
# download, by calculating last_time to hours (of the day) and
# after grouping build mean hour
ddf %>% 
  mutate(hours = as.numeric(lubridate::hms(last_time), unit = 'hour')) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% summarise(meanHourOfTheDay = mean(hours, na.rm = T))

#> # A tibble: 29 x 2
#>       id meanHourOfTheDay
#>    <int>            <dbl>
#>  1    11            11.9 
#>  2    12            14.0 
#>  3    14            14.6 
#>  4    15            12.8 
#>  5    16             2.45
#>  6    17             8.17
#>  7    18            12.1 
#>  8    19            15.4 
#>  9    20            17.7 
#> 10    21            14.4 
#> # … with 19 more rows
```

Comment: thanks for the simplified solution. Using for loop for splitting the data into multiple columns is much simpler.

Comment: Thanks a lot, MarBlo! You understood my problem correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code in your original data set. This might help you to answer the introductory, first part, third part and lastly the second part of the question.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
district <- c("A","A","B","B","C","C")
block <- c("X","Y","Z","X","Y","Z")
id <- c(11,11,12,12,13,13)
upload_dt <- ymd_hms(c("2020-06-13 11:31:07", 
                       "2020-04-12 14:23:29",
                       "2020-04-30 13:51:20",
                       "2020-06-12 11:53:15",
                       "2019-09-28 02:08:51",
                       "2020-04-12 16:23:29"))
df <- data.frame(district, block, id, upload_dt)
df <- df %>% 
    separate(upload_dt, into = c("date","time"),
             sep = " ", remove = F)
df$upload_date <- paste("last_upload_date_is", df$date)
df$upload_time <- paste("last_upload_time_is", df$time)
df <- df %>% 
    mutate(date_added = ymd(df$date),
           year_upload = year(date),
           month_upload = month(date)) 
df
```

The output for introductory and first part of the question is as follows:-

```
district block id           upload_dt       date     time                    upload_date
1        A     X 11 2020-06-13 11:31:07 2020-06-13 11:31:07 last_upload_date_is 2020-06-13
2        A     Y 11 2020-04-12 14:23:29 2020-04-12 14:23:29 last_upload_date_is 2020-04-12
3        B     Z 12 2020-04-30 13:51:20 2020-04-30 13:51:20 last_upload_date_is 2020-04-30
4        B     X 12 2020-06-12 11:53:15 2020-06-12 11:53:15 last_upload_date_is 2020-06-12
5        C     Y 13 2019-09-28 02:08:51 2019-09-28 02:08:51 last_upload_date_is 2019-09-28
6        C     Z 13 2020-04-12 16:23:29 2020-04-12 16:23:29 last_upload_date_is 2020-04-12
                   upload_time date_added year_upload month_upload
1 last_upload_time_is 11:31:07 2020-06-13        2020            6
2 last_upload_time_is 14:23:29 2020-04-12        2020            4
3 last_upload_time_is 13:51:20 2020-04-30        2020            4
4 last_upload_time_is 11:53:15 2020-06-12        2020            6
5 last_upload_time_is 02:08:51 2019-09-28        2019            9
6 last_upload_time_is 16:23:29 2020-04-12        2020            4
```

The code and the output for the third part of the question is as follows:-

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(avg_time_per_id = format(mean(strptime(time, "%H:%M:%S")), "%H:%M:%S")) %>% 
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 2
     id avg_time_per_id
  <dbl> <chr>          
1    11 12:57:18       
2    12 12:52:17       
3    13 09:16:10
```

The code and the output for the second part of the question is as follows:-

(Note for this I have created a new data frame.) You can apply this solution to the existing data set.

```
df <- data.frame(
    id = c(1:5),
    district = c("X","Y","X","Y","X"),
    block = c("A","A","B","B","C"),
    upload_date_a = paste0(rep("2020-06-13"), " ", rep("11:31:07")),
    upload_date_b = paste0(rep("2010-08-15"), " ", rep("02:45:27")),
    upload_date_c = paste0(rep("2000-10-30"), " ", rep("16:45:51")),
    stringsAsFactors = F
)
col_ind <- grep(x = names(df), pattern = "upload_date", value = T, ignore.case = T)
cols_list <- lapply(seq_along(col_ind), function(x){
    q1 <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(df[[col_ind[[x]]]], split = " "))
    q2 <- data.frame(q1, stringsAsFactors = F)
    i <- ncol(q2)
    colnames(q2) <- paste0(col_ind[[x]], c(1:i))
    return(q2)
    
}
)
df_new <- cbind(df[1:3], do.call(cbind, cols_list))
df_new


id district block upload_date_a1 upload_date_a2 upload_date_b1
1  1        X     A     2020-06-13       11:31:07     2010-08-15
2  2        Y     A     2020-06-13       11:31:07     2010-08-15
3  3        X     B     2020-06-13       11:31:07     2010-08-15
4  4        Y     B     2020-06-13       11:31:07     2010-08-15
5  5        X     C     2020-06-13       11:31:07     2010-08-15
  upload_date_b2 upload_date_c1 upload_date_c2
1       02:45:27     2000-10-30       16:45:51
2       02:45:27     2000-10-30       16:45:51
3       02:45:27     2000-10-30       16:45:51
4       02:45:27     2000-10-30       16:45:51
5       02:45:27     2000-10-30       16:45:51
```

Comment: Thanks, Sri Sreshtan! However, could you help me automate the splitting of variables? In the current dummy dataset I have 4 date/time columns but in real there are plenty. How can I choose them all at once and pass them through the separating function?

Comment: @Rachita . I have edited the above answer. Hope that helps.