# How can I include my percentages on the top of by bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

My apologies for my ineptitude... it's been a while since I had my R stats class and I've been trying to figure this out all day. I'm having some difficulty including percentages on the bars in my plot. Is it possible to do so with the script I already have?

```r
proj <- Master_List_for_R_Studio
#data prep
proj$Location <- as.factor(proj$Location)
head(proj, 3)
proj$Host <- as.factor(proj$Host)
head(proj,3)

#compute summary stats
proj.summary2 <- proj %>%
  group_by(Location, Host) %>%
  summarise(
    std.error = std.error(prv_aspido),
    prv_aspido = mean(prv_aspido)
  )
proj.summary2

#plot
asp.ab3 <-ggplot(proj.summary2, aes(Location, prv_aspido)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Host), position = position_dodge(0.8), width = 0.7) +
  labs(y= "Aspido.sp Abundance") +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(ymin = prv_aspido-std.error, ymax = prv_aspido+std.error, group = Host),
    width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.8)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
asp.ab3
```

With this script, I get the following plot, but I'd like to include percentages. I've also been referring to [Sebastian Sauer](https://sebastiansauer.github.io/percentage_plot_ggplot2_V2/)

[image: Current Plot]

Comment: FYI, code fences need to be on lines by themselves, as in `\`\`\`\n`, no code on the same line at all. I've made a suggested edit, please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/40249943/3358272, does that answer your question?

Comment: If you could share your data using `dput(proj.summary2)`, we can reproduce your problem.