# Bar chart side-by-side with percent frequency

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am using ggplot to create a side-by-side grouped bar chat using this:

```
ggplot(df,
       aes(descriptive_var,
           fill = as.factor(Var1))) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge")
```

which gives me absolute frequencies.

However, I want percent frequencies using this:

```
ggplot(df,
       aes(descriptive_var,
           fill = as.factor(Var1))) +
  geom_bar(position="fill")
```

which gives me a stacked bar chart.

How do I make a side-by-side grouped bar chat with percent frequencies? Do I have to run the counts and calculate the percentages manually? There are quite a number of variables so I hope not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249943/adding-percentage-labels-to-a-bar-chart-in-ggplot2

Comment: yes, thank you.